# Diagrammatic Reasoning Problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

I encountered the problem from other people's postings online. I'm not able to find anything interesting from the given diagrams. I have vague memory of tackling similar type of diagrams before and being not able to solve it.

I believe there must be some reasoning trick I've not mastered yet. Could someone please help me figure that out?

Comment: Might have something to do with the number of edges and corners...

Comment: @Valtteri Didn't think about that. I'll have a try. Thanks.

Comment: @Valtteri Oh my goodness! You are probably right! The answer may be  D. The numbers of edges are 2, 4, 6, 8, 10...Thank you very much. Feel free to add an answer if you'd like to :)

Comment: The "answer" could also be B, because that is the only choice making the area of the interiors of the figures strictly increasing.  So you see, this kind of problem is not a well-defined math problem.

Comment: [logic]$\neq$"Oh, that must be logical!".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Number of edges are $2,4,6,8...$ :D

Comment: You deserve it :)